# Communication between node.js servers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite a bit new to node.js. I have question, can we connect two node.js servers? these 2 servers handle clients and perform there individual action I want to establish a connection between these two servers so that these 2 servers can share there status to each other.

Can anyone please help me?

it is somewhat like this

server1 ==> room1[client1, client2,client3]

server2 ==> room2[client4,client5, client6]

here I want to make a communication between these two servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure: just use a [socket](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) as you would with any other programming language that's capable of network communications.

One of the servers will need to listen on a TCP port (using `net.createServer`) and the other one connects to it using `net.connect`.

This is easy if you really only have two servers. If you have more, you will need either a main "arbiter", i.e. a (listening) relay server that receives messages from other servers and transfer them to real recipients, or a [mesh network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking) (not a good starting point if you're a networking newbie).

[JsonSocket](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/json-socket-sending-json-over-tcp-in-node.js-using-sockets) seems to be an interesting project for transfering JSON messages using raw TCP sockets, although I didn't test it myself.

Comment: can you explain how to establish a connection if there are more than two nodejs servers,
Is there any module or framework for mesh network?
like every server should have the information of the other server.