# Share object between two node instances

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if it's possible to share a object between two node instances?

In the first instance, `node app1.js` I create the following object:

`const bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, { channels: config.channels });`

Is it possible to share this `bot` object with another node instance (`node app2.js`) and what would I need to use to share it?

Comment: You can create a simple HTTP server and send a request from one Node instance to the other.

Comment: @Swailem95 I was thinking to do the same, just curious if there "another" way as well.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I think HTTP requests are your safest option.

Comment: Is bot object is serializable to send over HTTP?

Comment: @SergeK. In short: I want to be able to use that `bot` instance object in `app2.js`. Longer version: I'm writing a relay from IRC to Telegram and vice versa. I want to seperate the relay bot from the bot that has general commands. The relay bot creates that `bot` instance, but with I need the bot with commands to get that instance as well since the output of the commands need to be relayed to IRC as well.

Comment: also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196161/communication-between-node-js-servers

Comment: So you have a bot that accept commands and outputs some text according to these, and a bot that relays messages from Telegram to IRC and back ?

Comment: @SergeK. that's correct.

Comment: Why do relay bot needs to know the "command" bot ? Since it seems to chat like any other party here, the relay bot should be able to forward its messages like the others ?

Answer (score 0):

as already mentioned you can go with http requests , since you wanted some other option you can also go with reddis(https://redis.io/) an in memory dataBase.or with mongoDB if you want more persistence.